# Content of a file package won't refresh: why?

Tags: macos, cocoa, filesystems, finder, nsfilewrapper

### Does anyone know this issue?

I am writing in a file package (with methods of `NSDocument`), via

```
[(NSFileWrapper *)content writeToURL:myURL
                             options:NSFileWrapperWritingAtomic | NSFileWrapperWritingWithNameUpdating
                 originalContentsURL:myURL
                               error:error];
```

When I look at the content of the file package, it is not updated: the new files won't appear and the old files stay there. If I try and open an old file (that is supposed not to be here anymore), I got an error message (in the `Finder`) : "can't find..."

What is the problem:

- am I playing in a wrong way with `NSFileWrapper`?
- is there a problem with updating infos of files "hidden" in packages?

---

### edit

- I don't have any `error` when writing.
- I am not using `NSDocument` methods because I need the support of Core Data. I use a classe called `BSManagedDocument` that subclasses `NSDocument`.
- A maybe related problem is that, when I don't use the `NSFileWrapperWritingAtomic` option, I get an error "cannot write, because a file (my directory!!!) called ... already exists"

Comment: What's the return code of `writeToURL:ofType:error:`?  What does the `error` variable look like after the call? How does the content of `myURL` look like before you call the method?  How about adding some basic error checking?

Comment: You're not using `NSDocument` calls to write the file. Why not? Are you making sure file access it synchronized with `NSDocument` when you're calling the `NSFileWrapper` methods directly..?

Comment: Thanks for helping!! See my edit. How can I "make sure file access it synchronized with NSDocument when I'm calling the NSFileWrapper methods directly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this - it appears to a be a Finder bug.  Are you looking at the contents of your file package by selecting the package in Finder and then right clicking to invoke the menu item **Show Package Contents**?

If so, that's a problem because Finder caches package contents and won't show you the updates.

Try looking at your file package contents in the terminal using the `ls` command as in:

```
ls -al /Path/to/Your/FilePackage
```

That should show the new package contents.